# How to set a background color for canvas element?

Tags: javascript, html, html5-canvas

I need to generate a canvas element that has its own background color and at its center some text that uses a image background:

```
==================
|                 |
|      Hello      |
|                 |
==================
```

Right now I can display a text filled with an image

```js
const init = () => {
  const canvas = document.getElementById("canvas")
  const context = canvas.getContext('2d')
  context.font = 'bold 140px Times'
  context.textBaseline = 'center'
  const image = new Image()
  image.src = 'https://img.redbull.com/images/c_crop,x_0,y_0,h_1080,w_1620/c_fill,w_1500,h_1000/q_auto,f_auto/redbullcom/2017/08/29/03820845-b090-444f-86d1-e5259d11482f/most-heroic-pokemon.jpg.jpg'

  image.onload = () => {
    const pattern = context.createPattern(image, null)
    context.fillStyle = pattern
    context.fillText('Lorem ipsum', 0, 200)
  }
}

init()
```

```css
canvas {
  border: 1px solid #000;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
</head>

<body>
  <canvas id="canvas" width="1920" height="1080"></canvas>
</body>

</html>
```

I know I can change the canvas background using css but I get a transparent png when I save the images using right click.

How can I set a black background for the canvas and set a text with its own background?

Answer (score 3):

The [Canvas API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Canvas_API) defaults to a black transparent background (the `imageData.data` on an unchanged canvas will be all zeroes where each set of four values indicates RGBA values). You can use `fillRect` in the Canvas API to set the background color of the [whole canvas](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/fillRect#filling_the_whole_canvas).

Note: You can set the [fillStyle](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/fillStyle) to change the color, but Canvas API defaults to `#000 (black)` for this property, so you only need to set it explicitly if it has been changed.

```js
const init = () => {
  const canvas = document.getElementById("canvas")
  const context = canvas.getContext('2d')
  context.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height)
  context.font = 'bold 140px Times'
  context.textBaseline = 'center'
  const image = new Image()
  image.src = 'https://img.redbull.com/images/c_crop,x_0,y_0,h_1080,w_1620/c_fill,w_1500,h_1000/q_auto,f_auto/redbullcom/2017/08/29/03820845-b090-444f-86d1-e5259d11482f/most-heroic-pokemon.jpg.jpg'

  image.onload = () => {
    const pattern = context.createPattern(image, null)
    context.fillStyle = pattern
    context.textAlign = "center"
    context.fillText('Lorem ipsum', canvas.width / 2, canvas.height / 2)
  }
}

init()
```

```css
canvas {
  border: 1px solid #000;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
</head>

<body>
  <canvas id="canvas" width="1920" height="1080"></canvas>
</body>

</html>
```

### EDIT

Thank you to [Roko](https://stackoverflow.com/users/383904/roko-c-buljan) for alerting me to the centering requirement of the question.

I made a few changes to my code to include horizontal and vertical alignment

**Horizontal**

```js
        context.textAlign = "center"
```

**Vertical**

```js
  // already implemented in your code
  context.textBaseline = 'center'
```

**Using `fillText` to center the text fully with the above settings applied**

```js
    context.fillText('Lorem ipsum', canvas.width / 2, canvas.height / 2)
```

Comment: and just center the text and you're done ;)